# DOMPDF Working in Mac not in Windows and CentOS

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using a DOMPdf in my Moodle Project,  In This I am trying to make a html as a pdf.  It is working perfectly in my local machine (Mac System).  I put the same code in a Windows machine and CentOS server; and it is not working.  I am trying for several hours I cannot get the solution.  I am using PHP 5 in all environments.

The solutions I tried:

1. Gave full Permissions (777) to DOMPDF folder.

following is my code

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$Test='<html>
        <head>

        <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
        <body>    
         Sample Text
        </body>
        </html>';
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($Test);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("test.pdf");
echo $dompdf;
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any errors? also, check `dompdf` requirements for `php.ini` include libraries, and specific `PHP 5` versions on all environments.

Comment: Hai Kuro thank you for the reply,  in the server(CentOS) I have this pdf in two places and it is working in one place.  So,  I hope php.ini is configured correctly.

Comment: ok. when i look at your code, you have `$Test` variable defined, and using `$printingout` in `$dompdf->load_html()` method. what is in '$printingout' variable?

Comment: Sorry that was a typeo error,  please see the code now.

Comment: did you make sure all the required components are installed on your win/centOs servers : http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Installation

Comment: Hai Eswar,  thank you for answering.  In the CentOS server the PDF is working for another site hosted.  So I hope the php configurations are done right.

Comment: @DilipRajkumar Which version of dompdf? Did you upload your site in full or perform a fresh install on the server?

Comment: @BrianS I tried with several versions of dompdf.  All gave me save issues.  Finally yesterday magically it worked in CentOS server, still it is not working on windows.  Same code we have in all environments..

Comment: @DilipRajkumar I would recommend 0.6.0 (currently at beta 3) or a nightly. Lots of improvements over 0.5.1. That said, we need more information in your question. For example, do you get any PHP errors? Are you just copying files or installing fresh on each server?

Comment: @BrianS Yes Brian I am copying files from my local to the server.  Is there an installation procedure for DOMPDF.  Because I have to deliver this along with a module.  Sorry If my information is not clear,  basically I am not a PHP developer.

Comment: I am not sure how to see php logs also it is a PLESK server.

Comment: @DilipRajkumar That could be the cause of your error. Some cached file paths may use a full path and thus point to the incorrect location on your server (unless the file system layout is the same). It's always best to install the library fresh on your new server (though we are working to improve portability). Try deleting lib/fonts/dompdf_font_family_cache or fixing the file paths in it.

Comment: @BrianS I can test this only on Monday..  Thank you for the answer... Please post it in answers so that it will help ppl in future...  Thanks once again...

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will help guys................

```
<?php
 require_once("C:/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$Test='<html>
    <head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
     Sample Text
    </body>
    </html>';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($Test);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("test.pdf");
//echo $dompdf;
?>
```

Comment: Hai @venkata bandla I have fixed the issue,  the issue is because of the giving 777 access to fonts folder.

Comment: Sure thank you verymuch.  Maybe it will help some one to sove the issue.